# Is it possible to use material-select with ngModel/ngControl

Tags: dart, angular-dart

How to use `<material-select>` with `ngModel` and `ngControl`?

Every time I try to use `<material-select>` with `ngModel` and `ngControl`, I get:

`EXCEPTION: Assertion failed: "No value accessor for (data) or you may be missing formDirectives in your directives list."`

Comment: Here is an example how to use it https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/tree/master/example/material_select_example

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this is exactly what I use. But there is no reference to `ngModel` and `ngControl`… And when I try to add them, I get the `EXCEPTION: Assertion failed: "No value accessor for (data) or you may be missing formDirectives in your directives list."`

Comment: I'm not sure. Lets wait until someone from the AngularDart team has a look.